# sap.m.FormattedText not working in the sap.m.CustomTile

Tags: css, sapui5

I want to make demo with sap.m.FormattedText nested in the sap.m.CustomTile in the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vonohebayi/1/edit?html,css,output). I do not know why I got this insted of the text SYSTEM SIZE:

[image]

The string I used is:

```
var sString = "&lt;p style=&quot;font-size:20px; color:#808080; padding-left:40px; &quot; &gt; SYSTEM SIZE &lt;/p&gt;" ;

var oFtext = new sap.m.FormattedText();
oFtext.setHtmlText(sString);
```

All code is in the jsbin [example](http://jsbin.com/vonohebayi/1/edit?html,css,output).

When I use the same string in the view it works:

```
<CustomTile>
   <Vbox>
       <FormattedText  htmlText='                                   
          &lt;p style="font-size:20px; color:#808080; padding-left:40px; margin-bottom:0px; "&gt; SYSTEM SIZE &lt;/p&gt;                                             
       '/>
   </Vbox>
</CustomTile>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are escaping the `<`, `>` and `'` characters. This is necessary on the xml file (it is actually just part of the specification of xml, as you can see in this  [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)) but not in the js file.

Write the html normally and it will work: `<p style='font-size:20px; color:#808080; padding-left:40px; ' >; SYSTEM SIZE </p>"`

Comment: Thank you Juan, I also upvoted. Here is correctly edited example http://jsbin.com/kucaqiyami/1/edit?html,css,output for others.